# Angular 2 - element title with localization pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript

We have a localization pipe ready and working. When I want to use it in table cell there's no problem with that.

```
<th class="dark-head">{{'entry.dateTimeTitle' | TDLocalize}}</th>
```

Is there a way to use it on element title? All of the methods I used, shown below, don't work.

```
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="'edit' | TDLocalize"></span>
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="edit | TDLocalize"></span>
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="{{edit | TDLocalize"}}></span>
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="{{'edit' | TDLocalize"}}></span>
```

**Problem solved**

I wasn't notified on the fact that you actually have to build resources solution in order for it to show new entries. Good example that the code is almost never self-commentary.

But at least I had chance to try what works and what crashes so here it is:

```
 <!-- Works -->
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="'edit' | TDLocalize"></span> 
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="getTitle(row) | TDLocalize"></span> 
 <span class="ic-18" title="{{'edit' | TDLocalize"}}></span>

 <!-- Does not crash but shows exact string in between "" -->
 <span class="ic-18" title="edit | TDLocalize"></span>
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="edit | TDLocalize"></span>  

 <!-- Does not crash but shows nothing -->
 <span class="ic-18" title="{{edit | TDLocalize}"></span>

 <!-- Crashes-->
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="{{edit | TDLocalize"}}></span> 
 <span class="ic-18" [title]="{{'edit' | TDLocalize"}}></span>
```

Comment: `<span class="ic-18" title="{{'edit' | TDLocalize"}}></span>` perhaps?

Comment: Throws error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More]`

Comment: Of course it did. I made a legit typo... `<span class="ic-18" title="{{'edit' | TDLocalize}}"></span>` (bad placement of closing `"` around the `title` attribute's value.)